# How to determine what bloks are allocated for the disk device?

Tags: windows, winapi, storage, virtualization, scsi

A lot of modern storage types use [Thin provisioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_provisioning) to allocate blocks. I need to get  [Block allocation map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_allocation_map) for the disk device. There is [FSCTL_GET_VOLUME_BITMAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364573(v=vs.85).aspx)  to get volume bitmap, but it is file-system specific and I need an approach that is not FS specific. 
Starting in Windows 8  [Windows is sending "TRIM and Unmap" hints to storage media to track allocated blocks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848053(v=vs.85).aspx).

> UNMAP is the SCSI command by which an application or the system can
>   communicate to the storage stack and the disk that a certain sector or
>   range of sectors are currently not in use, including sectors that were
>   previously in use by files that were later deleted.

So this should be possible. Unfortunately, I was unable to find  [Disk Management Control Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363979(v=vs.85).aspx) or Disk Management Function to get it. Maybe someone know know the way to get it?

Comment: I don't think there's any standard method.  The underlying storage can implement thin provisioning in any way it likes.  Trim and Unmap allow the OS to provide information to the storage device, not the other way around.

Comment: If you have SCSI drives, the GET LBA STATUS command introduced in SBC-3 is the way to retrieve the low-level mappings from the device itself.

Comment: @gubblebozer Thank you! That can be accepted. Looks like IOCTL_STORAGE_MANAGE_DATA_SET_ATTRIBUTES  can do this work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like gubblebozer made a hint - `GET LBA STATUS` command introduced in SBC-3 is the way to retrieve the low-level mappings from the device itself.  From [Thin Provisioning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn265487%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
The application can call the IOCTL DSM allocation routine to send the SCSI 
command and retrieve the mapped or unmapped state of each slab in a particular 
range. If the LBA provisioning status returned does not describe the entire 
allocation range, the application sends another SCSI command to retrieve the 
provisioning status of the remaining LBA range.
```

Looks like this can be done with the help of [IOCTL_STORAGE_MANAGE_DATA_SET_ATTRIBUTES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560573(v=vs.85).aspx) 
then [DEVICE_DATA_SET_LB_PROVISIONING_STATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404245(v=vs.85).aspx)  structure  will contain a bitmap of 
slab allocations.